# Content type changes to organic when exporting data from linkedin

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I tried exporting content analytics data from linkedin. When I open the data in excel or python all posts changed its post type from the original type (e.g. image or article) to organic.

I tried redownloading it but it keeps happening. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.